# Resolving an error in using the Crf++ toolkit

Tags: nlp

To all those who have had experience with using the crf++ toolkit (refer: http://crfpp.sourceforge.net/)

Please find the error message which pops up on trying to execute the CRF++ training program:

```
CRF++: Yet Another CRF Tool Kit
Copyright (C) 2005-2009 Taku Kudo, All rights reserved.

encoder.cpp(280) [feature_index.open(templfile, trainfile)] feature_index.cpp(86)     [max_size == size] inconsistent column size: 21 20 train.data
```

I'm not sure how to interpret the error message.
There are 20 features in my training file and the 21st token is the class value.
I have created the Crf++ template file as per the instructions on the site.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a training data format issue, make sure the number of columns are consistent across all sentences.

Comment: Yeah, that's what it was. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error today, and found that `crf++ toolkit` just set tab character(\t) to default column separator whereas my train data file using one white space lead to error.

Answer (score 0):

Some points to check:
1. Check if you have a new line after each sentence
2. Check if your columnar values does not contain any sp

Answer (score 0):

Error suggests that your number of columns in rows are not same among all. Your maximum number of columns are 21 and that should be consistent through out the training file but `crf_learn` finds it 20 somewhere in your `train.data` training file. So locate such row and remove/repair it.